# kourou throw error with Creating network "playground_default" with the default driver

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

## steps

I followed the [started instruction](https://doc.kuzzle.io/core/2/guides/getting-started/run-kuzzle/)  ,but the errors were threw after I run the kourou commonad `app:scaffold playground`

## Error

with Creating network "playground_default" with the default driver

(sorry for this short message,my host cannot log in.I will complete error message later)

I'm not sure it is related with that I install the kourou before docker-compose. (any permission problem had been solved)

## enviroment

Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS 64bit
Nodejs 14.17.1

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error? Also, make sure you have Docker and Docker-Compose on your computer and that your current user have the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I solved this problem just recently.

I ran the command in the REMOTE SSH of VSCODE before, and then an error occurred. But I just ran it again in ELECTERM(a cross-platform remote ssh terminal) and found that this time it passed when installing dependencies

I still wonder what happened, plz tell me what might be causing the error